# Connect a monitor with DisplayPort to a PC

Tags: display, displayport

I need to get a DisplayPort-connected monitor working on my PC.

I have bought a new monitor for my PC.   The monitor is a Samsung S27A850D, which utilities DisplayPort but not HDMI. My PC does not have a display port slot. Does this mean that I need purchase a new video/graphics card? Otherwise, how do I connect a DisplayPort cable to a PC which does not have a DisplayPort slot?

Comment: What slots do you have currently for video out? What slots do you have inside the system for add-in cards?

Answer (score 2):

There are adapters for various ports. See [DVI to DisplayPort options](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=displayport%20dvi%20cable&hl=en&cid=12668693189788253849&sa=title#p). But it looks like your monitor supports DVI and ships with a DVI cable. You should be able to use DVI from your video card to connect to it.

Doing some additional reading and that looks like a great monitor. To really drive it to it's full resolution you should use a video card that supports either [dual-link DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Dual-link_DVI) or [display port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort).